# CorelDRAW Font List shortcut not working

Tags: fonts, corel-draw, shortcuts

I have added a shortcut for Font List(Ctrl+shift+F) but it won't work unless opening Options (Ctrl+Alt+F) [image: (Ctrl+Alt+F)] and closing it, after that i can select my text and use the shortcut to change the font[image: font]

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: CorelDRAW 22.0.0.415